# Printing multiple html tables in email from python

Tags: python, smtplib

Is it possible to put more than one html table into a message sent with `smtplib` and `email`? Whenever I use `attach()` for more than one thing, it only adds the first.

Specifically, doing this:

```
   msg1 = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
   msg1['Subject]' = ' '
   msg1['From'] = me
   msg1['To'] = you
   part1 = MIMEText(fhtml, 'html')
   part2 = MIMEText(dhtml, 'html')

   msg1.attach(part1)
   msg1.attach(part2)

   s = smtplib.SMTP()
   s.connect('mailserver')
   s.sendmail(me, you, msg1.as_string())
   s.quit
```

doesn't work. Only `part1` gets attached.

Comment: Can you show the specific code you are trying that is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You may try

```
part1.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename='part1.xml')
part2.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename='part2.xml')
```

or

```
msg1 = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
```

Comment: I already have `msg1 = MIMEMultipart('alternative')`. Will try `add_header`

Comment: Sorry, then you could try the defaults without parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Here is a demo what I did.
The idea is to convert all the csv files to html tables and send them as one html. In this example: there are 3 csv files. I would like to attach csv0.csv as attachment, put csv1.csv and csv2.csv as html tables in email body.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import csv, os
from tabulate import tabulate
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
import smtplib
import mimetypes
from email import encoders
from email.message import Message

def csv2htmlTableStr(CsvFileName):
    # this function is adapted from
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36856011/convert-csv-to-a-html-table-format-and-store-in-a-html-file
    #
    # Open the CSV file for reading
    reader = csv.reader(open(CsvFileName))

    # initialize rownum variable
    rownum = 0

    # write <table> tag
    HtmlStr = ''
    HtmlStr += '<table>'
    # generate table contents

    for row in reader: # Read a single row from the CSV file

     # write header row. assumes first row in csv contains header
       if rownum == 0:
          HtmlStr += '<tr>' # write <tr> tag
          for column in row:
              HtmlStr += '<th>' + column + '</th>'
          HtmlStr += '</tr>'

      #write all other rows
       else:
          HtmlStr += '<tr>'
          for column in row:
              HtmlStr += '<td>' + column + '</td>'
          HtmlStr += '</tr>'

       #increment row count
       rownum += 1

     # write </table> tag
    HtmlStr += '</table>'

     # print results to shell
    #print "Created " + str(rownum) + " row table."
    return HtmlStr

me = "<from email>" # REPLACE THIS 
you = '<to email>' # REPLACE THIS

csv0 = "/tmp/csv_as_attachment.csv"
csv1 = "/tmp/csv_as_html_table1.csv"
csv2 = "/tmp/csv_as_html_table2.csv"

ctype, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(csv0)
if ctype is None or encoding is not None:
    ctype = "application/octet-stream"
maintype, subtype = ctype.split("/", 1)
fp = open(csv0)
# Note: we should handle calculating the charset
attachment = MIMEText(fp.read(), _subtype=subtype)
fp.close()

csv1Str = csv2htmlTableStr(csv1)
csv2Str = csv2htmlTableStr(csv2)

text = """
Here is the first table:

""" + csv1Str + """

Here is another table:

""" + csv2Str + """

"""

html = """
<html><body>
<p><b><font color='red'>Here is the first table:</font></b></p>
""" + csv1Str + """</p>
<p><b><font color='red'>Here is another table:</font></b></p>
""" + csv2Str + """</p>
</body></html>
"""

message = MIMEMultipart(
    "alternative", None, [MIMEText(text), MIMEText(html,'html')])

message['Subject'] = "Try to embed more than one html tables in email body"
message['From'] = me
message['To'] = you
attachment.add_header("Content-Disposition", "attachment", filename='csv0')
message.attach(attachment)
server = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
server.sendmail(me, [you], message.as_string())
server.quit()
```