# Convert CSV to a HTML table format and store in a HTML file

Tags: python, html, csv, powershell

I have tried few shell scripts to convert to a HTML table format but I didnt get desired output. Could anyone help here to convert CSV to a HTML table format using Python or PowerShell and store it into HTML file.

Comment: Something I have used like this: echo "<table>" ;
    while read INPUT ; do
            echo "<tr><td>${INPUT//,/</td><td>}</td></tr>" ;
    done < name.csv ;
    echo "</table>"

Answer (score 4):

This is easy with PowerShell. You can use the [ConvertFrom-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/ConvertFrom-Csv?view=powershell-7.2&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-3.0&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203) cmdlet to convert your csv to a object array and use the [ConvertTo-Html](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-html?view=powershell-7.2&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-6&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203) cmdlet to convert it to a html table. To store the html, use the [Set-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content?view=powershell-7.2&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-6&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203) cmdlet:

```
$myCsv = 
@'
Id, Name
1, Hello
2, World
'@

$myCsv | ConvertFrom-Csv | ConvertTo-Html | Set-Content -Path 'YOUR_PATH_HERE.csv'
```

*Output:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>HTML TABLE</title>
</head><body>
<table>
<colgroup><col/><col/></colgroup>
<tr><th>Id</th><th>Name</th></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>Hello</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>World</td></tr>
</table>
</body></html>
```

Note: If you need to load the csv from a file, you can either use the [Get-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Get-Content?view=powershell-7.2&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-3.0&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203) cmdlet to load it and convert it using the example above, or you can use the [Import-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-7.2&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-6&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203) cmdlet.

Comment: I have tried the above command previously before asking question here. The output table was not in good format.

Comment: I was happy with this one because it covered my PowerShell use case. like @louis says it's not in a terrific format, but it's quick and dirty and extensible. I wouldn't mind seeing something with more flexibility/customization. Thanks for sharing Martin.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you:

```
 import sys
 import csv
 if len(sys.argv) < 3:
    print "Usage: csvToTable.py csv_file html_file"
    exit(1)

 # Open the CSV file for reading

    reader = csv.reader(open(sys.argv[1]))

 # Create the HTML file for output

    htmlfile = open(sys.argv[2],"w")

 # initialize rownum variable
    rownum = 0

 # write <table> tag

   htmlfile.write('<table>')

 # generate table contents

for row in reader: # Read a single row from the CSV file

 # write header row. assumes first row in csv contains header
   if rownum == 0:
      htmlfile.write('<tr>') # write <tr> tag
      for column in row:
          htmlfile.write('<th>' + column + '</th>')
      htmlfile.write('</tr>')

  #write all other rows 
   else:
      htmlfile.write('<tr>')    
      for column in row:
          htmlfile.write('<td>' + column + '</td>')
      htmlfile.write('</tr>')

   #increment row count 
   rownum += 1

 # write </table> tag
   htmlfile.write('</table>')

 # print results to shell
   print "Created " + str(rownum) + " row table."
   exit(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

well, I think that the easiest way to do it is.

```
import pandas as pd

csv = pd.read_csv('csv_file.csv')
html_table = csv.to_html()

f = open('html_file.html', 'w')
f.write(html_table)
f.close()
```

try it out!